# Accumulate monotonically increasing sequence list to a linear list

Tags: python-2.7

Hi I'm new to python and in programming in general. 
I have a monotonic list, ex. `L = [1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,0,1...]`
And whenever the series reaches 0, I would like to take the previous value and add to the remaining of the list so the list becomes linear.

```
L_sequence = [1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,0,1...]
L_linear = [1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7,8,9,9,10,11,12,13,13,14...]
```

I know a nasty way to do this, but if any of you have a good solution, you are welcome to share.

Comment: Please include your 'nasty way' to do this, so that we may point out improvements. This is doable with a simple `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should solve your problem:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,0,1,2,3,4,5,0,1,2,3,4,0,1]
x = []
helperOne = 0
helperTwo = 0 
goForIt = False
for i in l:
    if i == 0:
        goForIt = True
        helperTwo = helperOne + helperTwo 

    if goForIt==True: 
        t = helperTwo + i
        x.append(t)

    else:
        x.append(i)
    helperOne = i  

print x
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 13, 14]
```